# Problemas para adicionar produtos a pagina com um form sem dar refresh!

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou tendo dificuldades para conseguir fazer funcionar este código, onde eu tenho um form:

```html
        <form action="../procs/proc_entrada-produto.php" method="POST" id="conteudo">
        <a href="../index.php">Voltar</a>
            <select name="conteudo">
            <?php  
            include_once('../procs/proc_conn.php');
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tb_produtos" ; /* Define a query de selecao de dados */
            $select = mysqli_query($conn, $query); /* Execução da query */
            while($dado = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){?>
                <option><?php echo $dado['nome_produto']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <button type="submit" id="addItem">Adicionar</button> <!-- Botão de confirmação -->
        </form>
```

Que adiciona um campo "select" com o valor dos produtos cadastrados no meu banco de dados e que envia para o arquivo "proc_entrada-produto.php":

```html
<?php
include_once('proc_conn.php');
$conteudo = $_POST['conteudo'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM tb_produtos WHERE nome_produto LIKE '%$conteudo%'";
$select = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
$dado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);

$id = $dado['id_produto'];
$ean = $dado['ean_produto'];
$nome = $dado['nome_produto']; 
$quant= $dado['quant_produto'];


?>
```

E por fim o javascript que faz com que este form seja executado sem dar refresh, porém não estou recebendo os dados das variáveis:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#conteudo").ajaxForm(function(){
            $(".lista").append(
            "<tr>"+
            "<td><?php echo $id; ?></td>"+
            "<td><?php echo $ean; ?></td>"+
            "<td><?php echo $nome; ?></td>"+
            "<td><input type='number'/></td>"+
            "<td><input type='number' readonly='true'/></td>"+
            "<td><input type='number' value='<?php echo $quant; ?>' readonly='true'/></td>"+
            "<tr>");
            });
    });
    </script>
```

O resultado que eu esperava era a cada clique no botão de submit era de adicionar um campo com os valores relativos ao campo de "select" que tem as informações dos nomes dos produto, por favor me ajudem!

Comment: `<?php echo $id; ?>` pra usar o php no javascript vai ter de processar a página, se não quer dar refresh deveria fazer uma chamada ajax e como o resultado atualizar a página

Comment: Como eu faço isso sem perder os dados de outras chamadas

Answer (score -2):

Ao executar o código php vai processar a página, você tem que fazer uma consulta ajax e depois atualizar a página, para não perder os dados grava eles no local storage antes de atualizar e pega logo após

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso? Sou iniciante